# How can you make the system print dialogue default in chrome?

Tags: printing, google-chrome

Chrome has its custom feature-limited print dialogue which i always skip in order to use the system print dialogue.

Is it possible to make the system print dialogue default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Chrome also supports a `--disable-print-preview` mode where the dialogue is completely removed.

```
google-chrome --disable-print-preview
```

To persist this, you'll need to hack around the existing launcher. The easiest way is with `alacarte` (the menu editor). Just add the flag before the `%U` so you're left with something like this as the command:

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --disable-print-preview %U
```

Comment: Wow, that was easy :) I'll just use that second shortcut from now on. Thanks!

Comment: To get this option always active for `chromium` installed via `snap` you should put it into `~/.chromium-browser.init` as described in https://askubuntu.com/a/1215010/19753