# Chromium snap conversion: Command line options

Tags: 18.04, chromium, snap

Ubuntu 18.04 allows the system wide definition of command line options that are passed to the Chromium browser provided by the package `chromium-browser`. The flags are set in the file `/etc/chromium-browser/default`. Example file content:

```
# Default settings for chromium-browser. This file is sourced by /bin/sh from
# /usr/bin/chromium-browser

# Options to pass to chromium-browser
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disk-cache-dir=/dev/shm"
```

Where can I set the command line options for the snap version (installed using `sudo snap install chromium` ) of the Chromium browser?

Comment: Although a review of https://snapcraft.io/blog/chromium-in-ubuntu-deb-to-snap-transition and https://snapcraft.io/chromium shows no difference documented for command line options in launching the Chromium browser, I understand you find the command line options specified in the file /etc/chromium-browser/default are ignored by the snap version of the chromium browser and need alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the snap version you can set `CHROMIUM_FLAGS` inside `~/.chromium-browser.init` with the same content as `/etc/chromium-browser/default`

For example

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--incognito"
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1837746

**Edit**

In addition to the flags, snap application doesn't have access to `/dev/shm`. Please use one of the following solutions:

- Install chromium in dev mode `snap install chromium --devmode` to disable confinement
- Use `/dev/shm/snap.chromium` instead of `/dev/shm` in your flag

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) I copied the old configuration file to the location but unfortunately my specified flag is not set.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have another problem, chromium snap are not allowed to write to /dev/shm as seen by the log `Failed to create directory: /dev/shm/Default/Code Cache/js` when running with your flags

Comment: I have been successful in running chromium with your flag by installing it in devmode (disable confinement) `snap install chromium --devmode`

Comment: Or you can create `/dev/shm/snap.chromium` which the snap have access to. `mkdir /dev/shm/snap.chromium` and set `CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disk-cache-dir=/dev/shm/snap.chromium"`