# How can you make the system print dialogue default in chromium?

Tags: printing, chromium, 21.04

When using the native print dialog in chromium (installed via `snap`) in Ubuntu 21.04, I get problems: it takes a long time to render, makes me unable to choose a page range (until the rendering is complete), and seems not to be able to work if not installed with extra permissions (with `snap install --devmode chromium`) (apparmor disables the access to the ppd file as can be seen from `journalctl`).

How do I make it use the system print dialog? (Always, no matter how it is invoked: from shell or from the menu/icon.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chromium snap conversion: Command line options](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1214392/chromium-snap-conversion-command-line-options)

Comment: @David In a sense,it does. But actually my initial problem was just "How can you make the system print dialogue default in chromium?" without knowing that there is a command-line option for this. Then I did some research and found the corresponding option.But I didn't know where to put it (for quite a long time); I didn't have the idea to search for something like "Where to put command-line options for chromium installed via snap".Then ultimately, I came across the cited Q&A, and finally had the problem solved. That Q&A is just the final piece of knowledge required to solve my initial problem.

Comment: @David I reformulated the question so that now that answer is just a part of the whole answer for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have problems with chromium's own print dialog (the "print-preview" one)--and I believe the recent snaps with chromium all have problems as described in the question--then you can simply switch to the system print dialog (with a button in the dialog or by invoking it with `Ctrl-Shift-P` instead of `Ctrl-P`).

Now we should think how to make this easier for the user of chromium: so that the user won't have to remember these tricks and so that the one won't be faced with the problematic print-preview dialog whenever one wants to print from chromium...

chromium has actually (like [chrome](https://askubuntu.com/a/434158/19753)) a command-line option that makes it use the system print dialog immediately instead of its own print-preview dialog. You should run it as:

```
chromium --disable-print-preview
```

But that's a one-time solution.

Now we should wonder how to conveniently always use this option whenever we start chromium (either from the menu/icon or from shell)... And after a while, I've found the answer:

To get this option always active for chromium installed via `snap` (for a user, i.e., yourself) you should put it into `~/.chromium-browser.init` as described in http://askubuntu.com/a/1215010/19753 :

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--disable-print-preview"
```